# Как отправлять почту, используя хостинг firebase

Tags: php, firebase

Всегда использовал PHP для отправки почты с моего webapp, но решил перейти на firebase, а он не использует php, подскажите каким образом можно отправлять сообщения на почту если использую хостинг firebase?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Сайт на хостинге firebase, в нем нет php. На этом сайте есть форма обратной связи. Мне нужно чтобы клиент не регистрируясь на сайте мог выслать email, или какое либо другое сообщение.